# How to limit Rollercoaster to 1 round only?

Tags: rollercoaster-tycoon-classic

Rollercoaster seems to loop more than 1, I don't want that. I want it go for only 1 round and then stop and let the guests disembark and take another set of guests.
How to do that?

Comment: To be clear, you're asking about the train making more than one circuit around the track, right?

Answer (score 3):

When you finish constructing a coaster and are in it's main menu. Select the configuration tab (it looks like gears) and on the first drop down, select "continuous circuit mode" This option may vary between rides(some may say "block section" as well).

There are additional options related to ride timing and speeds in this same menu, try tinkering with them!

If it is on continuous circuit and leaving the station too soon, try changing the minimum wait time and have the box checked. You could also have 'leave if another train is at the station" enabled, which will force a train to take off continuously if you have a short ride.